# What legally constitutes a change in "the pronoun" used to refer to a student?

Tags: language, north-carolina, notice, school-law, pronouns

In [the recently passed SL2023-106, also known as SB49](https://www.ncleg.gov/Sessions/2023/Bills/Senate/PDF/S49v5.pdf), the North Carolina state legislature decided to require schools to adopt a policy to notify parents of, among other things:

> Prior to any changes in the name or pronoun used for a student in school records or by school personnel, notice to the parent of the change.

(We will ignore how as written the law requires the parents to be notified *of notice*, and not of the event in question.)

Note that that they specifically write "pronoun", as in one pronoun, not a set of them, whereas people skilled in the art of gender more commonly refer to [a person's "pronouns", which are sets like "he/him/his"](https://lgbt.uni.edu/pronouns). I am not aware of any North Carolina statute defining the term "pronoun". I also note that this law does not include any mention of "second-person pronoun" or "third-person pronoun".

In English, it is common to use words such as "he", "his", and "himself", often all for the same person within the same sentence. **Would a teacher saying such a sentence about a student constitute a change in "the name or pronoun" used to refer to the student?** Or are "he", "his", "himself", etc. legally one "pronoun"?

In English, there is a second-person pronoun "you", which presumably is legally distinct from the third person pronoun "she". **Would a teacher referring to a student as "you" while addressing them, and then going on to refer to the student as "she" in the next sentence, constitute a change in "the name or pronoun" used to refer to the student?**

In schools, students will often learn foreign languages. In such classes, it is common for teachers to speak the foreign language, using its pronouns instead of the English ones, and sometimes even having students use names that are drawn from the language in question, for the class. **Would walking into or out of a foreign language class, or being spoken about by a teacher in a foreign language before or after being spoken about by a teacher in English, constitute a change in the "name or pronoun" used for the student?**

As far as I can tell, events requiring prior notification under the law happen to almost all the students, almost every day.

Comment: Laws aren't interpreted literally and in isolation like that.  You could read about [statutory interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_interpretation).  But here, I think to any reasonable person who pays an iota of attention to the world around them, it is obvious that the law refers to a change in *gender* pronouns, e.g. from "he" to "she" or "they".  I can't imagine anyone seriously believing that the legislature intended to cover the three cases you mention.  If someone tried to sue over a lack of notification for such an instance, it'd be dismissed as frivolous.

Comment: I hope they have to send a notice to a Rastafarian's parents that the student chooses to use I instead of me.

Comment: @NateEldredge so the law seems intended to, say, require a notification if a unit in Spanish is started and a student usually referred to as "he" is going to be given the Spanish female pronoun "ella", but not if the same student is going to be given the male pronoun "el", because we look beyond the text to the gender-essentialist thinking that motivated the drafters?

Comment: "Note that that they specifically write "pronoun", as in one pronoun, not a set of them, whereas people skilled in the art of gender more commonly refer to a person's "pronouns", which are sets like "he/him/his"." If you want to be this pedantic, the mistake in this case is made by people who call these pronoun*s*, plural. These are three forms of the pronoun *he*, not three distinct pronouns, much like "book" and "books" are two forms of the same noun, not two distinct nouns. (Btw to specify the full paradigm of an English pronoun one needs 4 forms, not 3: they / them / their / theirs.)

Comment: "*people skilled in the art of gender...*" What in the world does this even mean?!

Comment: @MichaelHall it's a fanciful turn of phrase, but I mean people who have taken courses in "gender studies", or who have taken enough mandatory workplace trainings about gender discrimination, or who have had to really think about pronouns and the sharing of them and are familiar with popular conventions for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  FWIW, I am solidly in favor of any tongue-in-cheek jabs at the militant language police.

Answer (score -1):

The law refers to whatever records and policies a public school unit has with respect to names. For example every public school unit has a record of each enrolled student that includes a name. If that record is changed, the parents must be notified. The public school unit may also have a policy mandating that all employees use the full name-of-record in referring to a student either in writing official records (therefore you cannot write "Bill" if the student's name-of-record is William), or in principle when speaking of the student. I've never heard of such a policy, but might be a current policy in some places.

A change in pronoun then refers to a record (e.g. an official designation that a student has the pronoun "she" or "he"), where one value is replaced with another value. It's pretty straightforward. It doesn't mean that schools have to adopt official pronoun or name policies, it just says that if they do have an official policy and record and they change a name or pronoun of record, the parents are to be notified.